# Add video in jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf

i am trying to put a video inside my `jsp` page, dynamically, like:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="420" height="345" controls="controls">
<source src="#{detailsBean.ref.videoLink}" type="video/ogg" /> </video>
```

But I get this error : `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /details.jsp(64,29) #{..} is not allowed in template text`

What should i use instead?

```
package beans;

import dto.Referinta;

public class DetailsBean
{
    Referinta ref  = new Referinta( );

    public Referinta getRef ( )
    {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef ( Referinta ref )
    {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

}
```

I dont think that the problem is in the bean, it's about the tag, can't find one to use with dynamic src. This will work if in src i put the direct link to the video.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `${detailsBean.ref.videoLink}` ?

Comment: @LaughDonor No, jsf doesn't use "$" that I'm aware of. Can we see your detailsBean.ref.videoLink code?

Comment: Oh jsf, I was reading as a jsp.

Comment: @LaughDonor it's okay :D